# spark python API java_gateway socket connection error

Tags: python, sockets, apache-spark, mesos

My cluster is `Spark-0.7.2` + `Mesos-0.9`. I wrote a spark program in python, and it runs well in local mode. But some errors occurred when I ran it on mesos. Here is the error info:

```
13/09/30 15:40:13 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished TID 13 in 242 ms (progress: 2/3)
13/09/30 15:40:13 INFO DAGScheduler: Completed ResultTask(4, 1)
send
Exception in thread "DAGScheduler" spark.SparkException: EOF reached before Python server acknowledged
        at spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorParam.addInPlace(PythonRDD.scala:303)
        at spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorParam.addInPlace(PythonRDD.scala:278)
        at spark.Accumulable.$plus$plus$eq(Accumulators.scala:52)
        at spark.Accumulators$$anonfun$add$2.apply(Accumulators.scala:235)
        at spark.Accumulators$$anonfun$add$2.apply(Accumulators.scala:233)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:93)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:93)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:660)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:157)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:190)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:43)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:93)
        at spark.Accumulators$.add(Accumulators.scala:233)
        at spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:494)
        at spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.processEvent(DAGScheduler.scala:300)
        at spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$run(DAGScheduler.scala:364)
        at spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anon$1.run(DAGScheduler.scala:107)
13/09/30 15:40:13 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished TID 12 in 407 ms (progress: 3/3)
```

This isn't happening every time. It seems the socket connection is not statable. Can someone suggest how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do the local and remote machines have different Python versions?  I've seen this problem when mixing a driver running on Python 2.7 with workers running Python 2.6.

Comment: i installed Python-2.7 on all computer and modified the .bashrc file. they all run on Python-2.7 now. the errors do not come out so frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating Java 8 to U91